# How to set tooltip to a string?

Tags: java

How to set tooltip to a string text with java?

```
"my_string".addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
            startTimer();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You don't add  mouseListeners to strings.  And a tooltip would be something that would pop-up when the mouse hovers over it.  Like a JMenuItem entry or anything that inherits from JComponent.  Please check the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Are you asking about tool tip or a mouse listener ?  Add the text to a `JLabel`.  A `JLabel` can have a tool tip as well as a mouse listener.

Comment: in fact i have 2 portion of text. like AAAAA-BBBBBB and i want BBBBBB to display info when mouse hover. when i use jlabel its result to alignement issue between the text portion(AAAAAA) and the jlabel